# Starting docker service in a CentOS image inside OpenStack breaks networking

Tags: docker, networking, centos, openstack

I have a CentOS image inside OpenStack which networks correctly, that is, I can SSH to it.

I need to start docker inside this image, because it is meant to run HyperLedger in the near future. So I had to install the latest docker repo and software, version 19.03.13.

Whenever I do systemctl start docker, I lose network connectivity to the image, and I can only reach it through the OpenStack terminal emulator.

Through it, I see that docker creates two new network interfaces (but it leaves the one that is configured for general networking alone) and also docker creates some iptables rules.

I have tried creating /etc/docker/daemon.json with the contents:

{
"iptables": false
}

But this does not solve the issue (it does prevent docker from creating most iptables rules, though).

I have acquired a tcpdump of the interface after docker is started, and while I try to SSH in from another machine (edited IPs for privacy):

```
12:13:12.298679 IP X.X.X.X.55628 > blockchain1-0.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1109271651, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2363748592 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:13:13.212493 IP blockchain1-0.34316 > dns.google.domain: 63674+ PTR? 5.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa. (39)
12:13:13.215497 IP dns.google.domain > blockchain1-0.34316: 63674 NXDomain 0/0/0 (39)
12:13:13.216495 IP blockchain1-0.33318 > dns.google.domain: 50843+ PTR? X.X.X.X.in-addr.arpa. (44)
12:13:13.219294 IP dns.google.domain > blockchain1-0.33318: 50843 NXDomain 0/0/0 (44)
12:13:13.300330 IP X.X.X.X.55628 > blockchain1-0.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1109271651, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2363749594 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:13:14.213681 IP blockchain1-0.33914 > dns.google.domain: 62995+ PTR? 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
12:13:14.216976 IP dns.google.domain > blockchain1-0.33914: 62995 1/0/0 PTR dns.google. (62)
12:13:15.316336 IP X.X.X.X.55628 > blockchain1-0.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1109271651, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2363751610 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:13:19.476352 IP X.X.X.X.55628 > blockchain1-0.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1109271651, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2363755770 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:13:27.668342 IP X.X.X.X.55628 > blockchain1-0.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1109271651, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2363763962 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:13:32.682139 ARP, Request who-has blockchain1-0 tell gateway, length 46
12:13:32.682154 ARP, Reply blockchain1-0 is-at fa:16:3e:35:73:ef (oui Unknown), length 28
```

The SSH connection never completes, a tcpdump from before starting docker is much longer and the SSH completes.

Does someone knows what is happening, or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'losing network connectivity'? I.e. is it possible to connect to a host on the public internet from within your instance? And, is it possible to ping the instance? Also, can you see any relevant traffic on the interface that provides ssh connectivity?

Comment: By 'losing network connectivity' what I mean is: I cannot initiate SSH sessions, and any SSH sessions that were open become hanged. The instance can be accessed only from inside our internal network. But it can initiate access any host on the internet. I have just tried pinging 8.8.8.8 before and after starting the docker service: before it is perfectly normal, and afterwards it is also normal. I have counted packages received and transmitted on the interface before and after a ping -c 3 8.8.8.8, and both rx and tx increase by exactly 3.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're initiating the SSH session from another instance in the same subnet? Can you run tcpdump on the interface with the IP address that you are SSH'ing to?

Comment: I added a tcpdump about when docker is started and a SSH session is attempted.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms that traffic is actually reaching the instance. You blocked the IP addresses, but it makes sense that docker has added a route that forwards your traffic to the container. What IP range do you have configured for your subnet? https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range/936255#936255

Comment: Thank you @BakaKuna, one of my users discovered that setting static IPs for the docker images solves the issue, so I believe the link you provided would also work. I'd close this question as duplicate of that one.